# Assign Ctrl+Tab as switch images in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, shortcuts

Is there a way to assign `Next Image` and `Previous Image` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> respectively?

I've tried using the keyboard shortcuts dialogue but I can't seem to get it to work. I click on the function, it says "New accelerator..." and seems to be waiting for me to input the shortcut but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does nothing.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The Tab key can't be used as a shortcut key, at least not in Windows, and not just in GIMP, it also can't be used in Photoshop either.

Comment: @BillyKerr It already works that way in Photoshop, though.

Comment: Yes, but I mean you can't use the Tab key to custom define shortcuts in Photoshop generally - the behaviour of Ctrl+Tab is built into Photoshop and is reserved for that purpose. What you could do in GIMP instead is set the shortcut to Ctrl+` (the Backtick key is located just above the Tab key).  This shortcut also works in Photoshop BTW.

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't really want to assign some other shortcut. What I wanted is the normal and expected functionality. But whatever, I can't have that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Control+PageUp/Down can be used to navigate images open in different tabs; Not ideal but just as handy if those keys happen to be accessible on your keyboard layout.

Comment: @MRule Thanks, although I would disagree about "just as handy". If I have to take my right hand off my mouse to complete a keyboard shortcut, it's not a good keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because the <kbd>Tab</kbd> is reserved for the GTK library (Gimp's UI is based on GTK). For some details see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1088058/how-can-i-bind-a-key-shortcut-that-includes-a-tab).

This explains why you can't assign that combination in the keyboard shortcut editor, the editor doesn't see that key event when you enter it.

Even trying to bypass the editor and enter something like:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/windows/windows-show-display-next" "<Primary>Tab")
```

in the `menurc` file in your Gimp profile, doesn't work. The UI ignores it and the shortcut editor flags it as invalid.

Comment: Well that's... stupid. So it's just impossible to assign a standard keyboard shortcut because the GTK devs decided tab couldn't be used? Wow.

Comment: What really should happen is that the Ctrk-tab is used in a tabbed display to navigate the tabs. Note that Gimp currently uses the obsolete GTK2. Things could be better wit the GTK3 that will be used in Gimp 3.0.